# SimpleDialogOption text and image in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, text, dart, popup

I have created a pop-up menu with SimpleDialogOption. But, I cannot add image and text at the same time.

```
  child: new SimpleDialog(
    title: new Text('Select your team',
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  letterSpacing: 1.3,
                  color: Colors.redAccent[700],
                    ),),
    children: <Widget>[

      new SimpleDialogOption(child: new Text('ANK'),onPressed: (){Navigator.pop(context, Answers.ANK);},),
      new SimpleDialogOption(child: new Text('ANT'),onPressed: (){Navigator.pop(context, Answers.ANT);},),
```

Here, I would like to have an image for ANK and another image for ANT. Text should stay below images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return SimpleDialog(
      title: Text('Title', 
        textAlign: TextAlign.center, 
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          letterSpacing: 1.3,
          color: Colors.redAccent[700],
        ),
      ),
      children: <Widget>[
        SimpleDialogOption(child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset('assets/Image.png', height: 140, fit: BoxFit.contain,), // Your image here
            SizedBox(height: 10,), // Optional to give some extra space
            Text('Image 1'),
          ],
        ),onPressed: () {},),
        SimpleDialogOption(child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset('assets/Image.png', height: 140, fit: BoxFit.contain,),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            Text('Image 2'),
          ],
        ),onPressed: () {},),
      ],
    );
  }
);
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have one more question. How can I create something like a table with 5 columns and 7 rows? I tried `column()` and `row ()` but I always get an error.

Comment: There is a table widget in flutter you can use. what kind of errors are you getting using rows and columns?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you're in need of a Column :

```
SimpleDialogOption(child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Image(),
        Text("ANK")
      ],
    ));
```